# Eclipse Pydev error

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I am using Win 8, Eclipse and Pydev. I installed Pydev and it can run simple python script.
Unfortunately I want to use math module and it gets error sign next to math command. 
[image]

Undefined variable.

I would be very thankful if you can help me to get rid of the error sign.

Best regards,
Peter

Comment: from math import *

print "Hello World!!!"
print 1+1

print ceil(2.2)

Comment: Nest to the print ceil(2.2), there is an error which says "Undefined Variable"

Comment: Do I need to put some link Windows->Preferences->Pydev->Interpreter Python to the math module?

Comment: If you need help, post a screenshot that is big enough for people to read. Even better, post the code as well so we can see what you've done. Finally, indicate whether or not the code runs despite the error flag in the IDE.

Comment: Are you able to run the code? Sometimes IDEs make errors too.

Answer (score 2):

'math' should be marked as a 'forced builtin' in window > preferences > pydev > interpreter - python (if it's not, that's your problem).

If it's properly configured, it probably means that PyDev wasn't able to spawn a shell to inspect the math module, in which case it usually means that there's some firewall blocking that communication (if so, usually there are entries in your error log -- see: http://pydev.org/faq.html#when_i_do_a_code_completion_pydev_hangs_what_can for more details).

Comment: math module is within pane as 'forced builtins'. I hope this is OK. but I do not know how to find firewall blocking under Win 8

Comment: I don't either, but google should help there (did you check the error log?)

Comment: Note: see http://pydev.org/faq.html#PyDevFAQ-HowdoIReportaBUG%3F for details on how to find the error log.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see the screenshot very well, but i see you are doing on the first line:

```
from math import *
```

and then

```
print math.whatever
```

Clearly `math` is an undefined variable here, as you should have used `import math` instead of `from math import *`

Comment: Next to the math command I am getting error "Undefined Variable"

Comment: do I need to add some link into Windows->Preferences->Pydev->Interpreter to math module?

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing `from math import *` you are essentially collapsing the math `namespace` onto the current `namespace` (`global namespace`). This means that you do not need to prepend the name `math` in front of attributes that were imported this way.

So you have two possible solutions:

1. Either `import math`, which doesn't collapse the math namespace, but allows you to refer to attributes of the math module by prepending math, followed by the dot and then the attribute name
2. Or use the attributes without prepending anything, as they are copied in your namespace and you can use them as if you had defined them in your script yourself.

For example.

1. For the first case something like `math.sqrt()` should do
2. For the second case `sqrt()` should do.

Answer (score 0):

In the PyDev Interpreter configuration pane you need to make sure that PyDev knows where to find the python packages.

Go to Preferences -> PyDev -> Interpreter - Python (or whatever interpreter is good for you).
After selecting the interpreter, click on the Apply button. This may resolve your issue if the ceil function wash't properly registered.